# i wanted to get the user details by integrating the API with curl php after getting access token

Tags: php, curl, phpmyadmin, php-curl

I wanted to get the user details by integrating the API with curl PHP after getting access token , I could log in and am getting the access token too`enter code here`.
here is the code with which am trying to get all the user details

```
<?php
$a = $_SESSION['token'];
$form_data = $a;

$str = http_build_query($form_data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "API");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);
?>
```

am getting error

Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. Incorrect value given in C:\xampp\htdocs\feedback\tables.php on line 11
string(73) "{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}"

Comment: it seems you are passing a string (token) to the http_build_query function. May you try?: $form_data = ['_token'=>$a];

Comment: thank you for the help ,the promblem is am getting this error {"Message":"The requested resource does not support Http method 'POST'."}"

Comment: I understand, and, is the api you are consumming supposed to accept post request at that particular route?